# Background color for excel file with Pandas: problem with single column boundaries (for outliers)

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, background-color, outliers

I need to export an excel where the outliers of my dataset are highlighted in yellow. As you know, calculated with upper bound and lower bound.

I've managed to set up the function, I just can't get it to work in an iterated way so the bounds are for each column.

When I export the dataframe into an excel file, it colours the cells based on the outliers of only one variable. It doesn't work in iterated mode.

Here my code, where am I wrong?

Here I just calculate for each column the lower and the upper bound (except for Subject ID)

```
for col in dfm.columns.difference(['Sbj']):
Q1c = dfm[col].quantile(0.25)
Q3c = dfm[col].quantile(0.75)
IQRc = Q3 - Q1
lowc = Q1-1.5*IQR
uppc = Q3+1.5*IQR
```

I set the function to colour the single value based on the limit values (not iterated)

```
def color(v):
if v < lowc or v > uppc:
    color = 'yellow'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

apply the function iteratively for each column

```
for col in dfm.columns.difference(['Sbj']):
df_colored = dfm.style.applymap(color)
```

It is obvious that something is wrong with the iteration.

Many thanks!!

Comment: in your loop, you did not use col variable!

Comment: hello @Phoenix, I tryed to set col = df[col] inside the loop, but still didn't work. Where should I set col?